# How to detect which requirement installed a package

Tags: python

I'm looking for installation tree in python, meaning which imported requirement requires a specific package.

Is there an efficient/easy way producing the tree?

Comment: Have you checked [pipdeptree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/)?

Answer (score 1):

## pipdeptree

As one of the comments mentioned, [`pipdeptree`](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) is a great tool.

If you are using `pyenv`, it may not produce accurate results and you may have to run it like this:

```
pip install pipdeptree

python -m pipdeptree
```

## pip-tools

Another great tool which serves a slightly different purpose is `pip-compile` which comes with [`pip-tools`](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools).

It allows you to generate a requirements file (for `pip install`) that contains all the packages and versions while also showing which packages have been pulled in by what.

The resulting `requirements.txt` file will look like this:

```
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile
# To update, run:
#
#    pip-compile --output-file=requirements.txt requirements.in
#
alembic==1.5.5
    # via flask-migrate
click==7.1.2
    # via flask
dnspython==2.1.0
    # via email-validator
dominate==2.6.0
    # via flask-bootstrap
...
...
...
```